# Running Batch File As An Administrator…

Tags: batch, administrator, batch-file, runas

I successfully created a batch file to flush my DNS.

I have added a pause, I noticed in the title bar of the console window… It's not running as administrator.

I've already tried a couple of variations of this… Just a little guidance would be most appreciated.

I remember reading a blog somewhere, it said something about capitalization wasn't important… Is camel casing important in writing batch files?

```
@echo off
echo.
pause
CD..
CD..
echo.
runas /user:<Administrator> ipconfig /flushdns
echo.
pause
echo.
```

Comment: This has been answered already at: http://superuser.com/questions/788924/is-it-possible-to-automatically-run-a-batch-file-as-administrator

Answer (score 1):

The user name must be in one of the following two forms:

> If you want to use the Administrator account on your computer, for the /user: parameter, type one of the following:
>
> /user: AdministratorAccountName @ ComputerName
>   /user: ComputerName \ AdministratorAccountName

The spaces around the "@" and the "\" should **not** be present - I suspect that they are there to make it easier to read.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx)

Comment: @RandolphWest - I wondered about that, but that's how it's written in the Technnet documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Either Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> while opening the program or Right click on the program and click on Run as administrator.