# Replace / Edit host file with windows BAT

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, hosts-file

I wish to add and remove some lines in host file within a period of time (Time setting will be done via task schedule job)

I can create two BAT file, one for adding new lines and one for removing existing lines.

After some research in Google, i could only find something related to ADD new lines, but not remove it. (replace) and mostly were subject to one line. As i had a huge chunk of lines need to insert and remove.

Any ideas or suggestion? 
(not sure will it be better to replace the HOST file physically.)

some findings related.

[Is it possible to automatically run a batch file as administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/788924/is-it-possible-to-automatically-run-a-batch-file-as-administrator)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666740/windows-batch-how-to-add-host-entries
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208429/how-to-replace-a-string-in-the-host-file-using-batch
http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r26962139-Other-Adding-entries-to-HOSTS-file-by-batch-script

Comment: Would like to remove all old lines or some? Do you know the line number?

Comment: see https://www.wincert.net/forum/topic/11460-delete-lines-from-the-hosts-file-via-bat/