# Why "Windows Time" service always is set to Manual in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, date-time

I have a laptop with a battery damage. I plug to energy only once a day.
When I turn on always the time is wrong.

Searching I found that the problem is "Windows Time" service is set to Manual (Trigger Start)" and the solution is just set it to "Automatic". I dit change it, but everytime I turn on, the laptop has a wrong time and the "Windows Time" service is again in Manual.

Do you know why and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you connected to a Active Domain.  This service should not be set to manual, the default setting, actually is automatic.

Comment: Nope... I'm not in an Active Directory. I'm at home. Only my computer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at 2 different places.

- in services.msc the service called "Windows Time" is indeed always "manual trigger start", as it only needs to run when it is required by the control panel.
- The suggestion you have found is ACTUALLY in the control panel:

You can use the new configurator to see if this is enabled (it will be by default):

1. Touch/Left-Click the clock (bottom right of your screen).
2. Click the blue text at the bottom: "Data and Time settings".
3. The first option should be 'toggled on': "Set time automatically".

You probably find it already is, and just you want your PC to IMMEDIATELY update time, instead of the seemingly random intervals that windows chooses. The simplest way is to write a script:

```
w32tm /resync
```

Once you are happy, **save that code as a batch** and [run it as administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/788924/is-it-possible-to-automatically-run-a-batch-file-as-administrator).

*
You could then just place a shortcut (run as admin) in your startup items folder

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

If you would like to test it first open a command-prompt (as admin): press <kbd>[Winkey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HckrW.png)</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, to bring up advanced menu, now just tap tap <kbd>A</kbd> or choose "Command Prompt (Admin)".

Comment: The "Set Time Automatically" is always turned on... So the solution was the bat file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe, just maybe, the baterry of BIOS is done and you have to replace it. It happened in the past to me, but it's once every five years situation only.

You know, if that battery has no charge at all, every time you shutdown your laptop, everything in BIOS (Including the date and time) is resetted.

Comment: Thanks Ppica88! I spend a lot of time yesterday and this morning. Advice to fiddle with the windows time service did not work. I saw your post and check the battery -> dead. Replace it and the time works perfectly again! CAUTION: you may need to update your BIOS or set it to defaults again.