# Once BAT is compiled into an EXE, I can't get embedded EXE's to run properly

Tags: batch, batch-file, conversion

I have created a batch file that lets me change the static IP Address or enable DHCP of my network adapters. It works wonderfully. I execute several EXE files written by Horst Schaeffer. They are Wbox, Wbusy, and winput (found here: https://www.horstmuc.de/wcon.htm). These programs are located in the same folder as my BAT. I also use another BAT written by Artur Zgadzaj to give my window admin privileges (https://superuser.com/a/921887).

(BTW, I was unable to get any of the other options on the linked page to work besides Zgadzaj's. If you have a simpler solution, please let me know.)

**ISSUE:**

When I try to make the BAT and EXE through iexpress, it runs up until the first popup screen and displays the pop-up. But once a selection is chosen, the program closes instead of continuing to run.

*This code is basically what I am doing but much more simplified and lots of added text for your clarification:*

```
@ECHO off

:TOF

:: ECHO This is a test file.
:: ECHO.
:: ECHO First, we will give this cmd window admin privileges.
:: PING localhost -n 4 >NUL

:Admin_Priv
    :: Run Batch_Admin.bat to auto-promt admin privilages
    net session >nul 2>nul&if errorlevel 1  Batch_Admin "%~0" %*

:: ECHO.
:: ECHO We will now check admin privileges.
:: PING localhost -n 4 >NUL

:check_Permissions2
    ECHO.
    ECHO Detecting permissions...
    net session >nul 2>&1
    if %errorLevel% == 0 (
        echo Success: Administrative permissions confirmed.
    ) else (
        echo Failure: Current permissions inadequate.
    )

:: ECHO.
:: ECHO The main part of the file will now begin...
:: PING localhost -n 4 >NUL

:Num_0
    ECHO.
    ECHO This in Number 0
    WBOX "Go To what?" "Choose" "1;2;Write Something" /BW=110
    GOTO Action_%errorlevel%
        :Action_1
        GOTO Num_1
        :Action_2
        GOTO Num_2
        :Action_3
        GOTO W_S

:Num_1
    ECHO.
    ECHO This in Number 1
    PAUSE
    WBOX "Go To what?" "Choose?" "0;2;Write Something" /BW=110
    GOTO Action_%errorlevel%
        :Action_1
        GOTO Num_0
        :Action_2
        GOTO Num_2
        :Action_3
        GOTO W_S

:Num_2
    ECHO.
    ECHO This in Number 2
    PAUSE
    WBOX "Go To what?" "Choose" "0;1;Write Something" /BW=110
    GOTO Action_%errorlevel%
        :Action_1
        GOTO Num_0
        :Action_2
        GOTO Num_1
        :Action_3
        GOTO W_S

:W_S
    ECHO.
    ECHO You can write something in the next pop-up box and have it display here.
    PAUSE

    ECHO.
    TYPE nul >temp.cmd
    winput "Type Words" "set WORD_CHOICE=$input" "write what you wish to be displayed in cmd." "(Enter text here)" > temp.cmd
    call temp.cmd
    DEL temp.cmd
    ECHO You typed:
    ECHO %WORD_CHOICE%
    ECHO.
    PAUSE

    ECHO.
    WBOX "Go To what?" "Choose?" "0;1;2" /BW=110
    GOTO Action_%errorlevel%
        :Action_1
        GOTO Num_0
        :Action_2
        GOTO Num_1
        :Action_3
        GOTO Num_2
```

*When activating all the commented commands at the beginning, it runs right up to the pop-up and closes. I added them in this code (not my original) to see what was going on and what was causing the close.*

I've tried creating this in "Advanced BAT to EXE" as well so that I could remove the Admin script and have the program auto prompt for privileges, but a very similar thing occurs.

I'm sure it has something to do with recalling the EXE programs and/or storing their temp information, but I haven't a clue on how to solve that. I'm only a novice amateur creating these things to simplify my work-flow as an artist.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the reason you want to make an exe off this? To hide code and make it look like an actual application? If so, I would suggest you just use a proper language to create a proper app.

Comment: Which program would you suggest? I have ample time to learn one, I just don't know which to begin with.

Cheers.